# How can I find all text nodes between two element nodes with JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, traversal

Given the following HTML-Fragment:

```
<div>
  <p>
    abc <span id="x">[</span> def <br /> ghi
  </p>
  <p>
    <strong> jkl <span id="y">]</span> mno </strong>
  </p>
</div>
```

I need an algorithm to fetch all nodes of type Text between `#x` and `#y` with Javascript. Or is there a JQuery function that does exactly that?

The resulting Text nodes (whitespace nodes ignored) for the example above would then be:

```
['def', 'ghi', 'jkl']
```

Comment: Do you want to grab the text nodes or their (string) contents?

Comment: Also, note that there are more than 3 text nodes between those two SPANs. (I think 5, but I'm not sure)

Comment: @Sime: I want to grab the text nodes.

Comment: @user In that case the result wouldn't be `['def', 'ghi', 'jkl']` but an array of DOM Text Node objects

Comment: Seems like you might need to combine https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203958/jquery-recursive-iteration-over-objects with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery.

Comment: What's your final goal? Find the text between [ and ]?

Comment: @ShadowWizard The final goal is to highlight the text between the two anchor nodes by wrapping the text nodes in span elements which have a certain css class that sets a background color. Much like selecting some text on a webpage and saving this selection for later reference.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following works in all major browsers using DOM methods and no library. It also ignores whitespace text nodes as mentioned in the question.

Obligatory jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/timdown/a2Fm6/

```
function getTextNodesBetween(rootNode, startNode, endNode) {
    var pastStartNode = false, reachedEndNode = false, textNodes = [];

    function getTextNodes(node) {
        if (node == startNode) {
            pastStartNode = true;
        } else if (node == endNode) {
            reachedEndNode = true;
        } else if (node.nodeType == 3) {
            if (pastStartNode && !reachedEndNode && !/^\s*$/.test(node.nodeValue)) {
                textNodes.push(node);
            }
        } else {
            for (var i = 0, len = node.childNodes.length; !reachedEndNode && i < len; ++i) {
                getTextNodes(node.childNodes[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    getTextNodes(rootNode);
    return textNodes;
}

var x = document.getElementById("x"),
    y = document.getElementById("y");

var textNodes = getTextNodesBetween(document.body, x, y);
console.log(textNodes);
```

Comment: Instead of `document.body` I think I can use the common parent node of both the start node and the end node as root node.

Comment: @user375773: Indeed, I agree that would be better. I omitted that for the sake of simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

The following example uses jQuery to find any two elements that are next to each other and may or may not have text nodes between them. This foreach loop will check the resulted elements to find any text nodes and add them to the list.

```
function getTextNodes() {
    var list = [];
    $(document.body).find("*+*").toArray().forEach(function (el) {
        var prev = el.previousSibling;
        while (prev != null && prev.nodeType == 3) {
            list.push(prev);
            prev = prev.previousSibling;
        }
    });
    return list;
}
```