# jquery .each objects

Tags: jquery, each

i am building an jQuery plugin, but i want to use objects in the options var, how can i loop this with the jQuery each?

plugin options var

```
        var defaults = {
            test: 'yes',   //css/classes
            type: {
                minvalue: '100',
                maxvalue: '200',
                name: 'id1'
            },
            type: {
                minvalue: '200',
                maxvalue: '300',
                name: 'id2'
            },
            type: {
                minvalue: '300',
                maxvalue: '400',
                name: 'id3'
            }               
        };


            $.each(defaults, function(key, value) { 
              alert(key + ': ' + value); 
            });
```

Comment: Those are objects, not arrays. You are overwriting them over and over.

Comment: ah, okay, i will change the info :)

Comment: @Niklas is right, but this might help too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203958/jquery-recursive-iteration-over-objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your example it is a bit difficult to figure what exactly you are trying to do, but if you want to use `arrays` and `$.each`, you could do this:

```
 var defaults = {
            test: 'yes',   //css/classes
     types: [
         {
                minvalue: '100',
                maxvalue: '200',
                name: 'id1'
            },
         {
                minvalue: '200',
                maxvalue: '300',
                name: 'id2'
            },
         {
                minvalue: '300',
                maxvalue: '400',
                name: 'id3'
            }


         ]

        };

$.each(defaults.types, function(index, value) { 
              alert(value.name + ': ' + value.minvalue); 
            });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/kFjVN/