# Print value of json with jquery in tag <p>

Tags: jquery, json

I wanted it inside the tag "p" was referring to the first value: query > results > guitars > guitar > second make. is possible ?

javascript:

```
$.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20xml%20where%20url%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fcristianoveloz.com%2Fpodcast5%2Fscripts%2Fguitars.xml'&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=?", function(data){

    console.log(data);


         });
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/22Ecw/60/)

Comment: you wanted what inside the p? yes, it's possible.

Comment: This guy had the same problem:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203958/jquery-recursive-iteration-over-objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do exactly what you ask you should use:

```
$(".make-text").html(data.query.results.guitars.guitar[1].make);
```

Of course you can see that `data.query.results.guitars.guitar` is an array so you can go though all items and print them all if you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

A very verbose way to do it, but see http://jsfiddle.net/22Ecw/62/

```
$.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20xml%20where%20url%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fcristianoveloz.com%2Fpodcast5%2Fscripts%2Fguitars.xml'&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=?", function(data){
             console.log(data);
               $('.make-text').text(data.query.results.guitars.guitar[1].make);
         });
```

Comment: If you're going to be doing a lot of data binding from JSON, i'd suggest using a library like handlebars.js