# Can we read values from this type of JSON array

Tags: jquery

I have the following JSON .
I am reading the T3 array .

My question is that is it possible to read the values Can and Bottle

```
 var jsondata =  {
        "T3": [
            {
                "Can": [
                    {
                        "type": "pepsi can 250ml"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "pepsi can 100ml"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "Bottle": [
                    {
                        "type": "pepsi bottle 250ml"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "pepsi bottle 100ml"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    };
```

I agree that at my knowledge , i can't proceed further from this level ??

```
for(var c=0;c<jsondata.T3.length;c++)
{


}
```

But still i want to ask whether this can be done or not ??

Answer (score 0):

Basically you now want to use the `c` variable to reference the relevant section of the `T3` array:

```
for(var c=0;c<jsondata.T3.length;c++){
  var can_data = jsondata.T3[ c ][ "Can" ]; // T3[ 0 ][ "Can" ]
  var bottle_data = jsondata.T3[ c ][ "Bottle" ]; // T3[ 0 ][ "Bottle" ]
}
```

Comment: Hi , I used your function this way , please see the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/AyuAY/ , from the obtained result can i extract  Can and Bottle from that ??

Comment: I mean to say that , if this line gets executed  var result = jsondata.item.T1[a].T2[b].T3[ c ]; , it produces two arrays {"Can":[{"type":"coke can 250ml"},{"type":"coke can 100ml"}]}  and {"Bottle":[{"type":"coke bottle 250ml"},{"type":"coke bottle 100ml"}]}  , so can i extarct the values Can and bottle from the obtained array . (I need this because Can and Bottle will be fecthed from Database dynamically and i dont konow what values might exist )

Comment: Sure you can - you just reference them as a normal JS object.

Comment: So should i create an array and push the results ?? but then how can i fetch Can and Bottle from that ??

Comment: you should put the results wherever makes sense in  your code. In the same way that you accessed it before: `some_obj[ "Can" ]`

Answer (score 0):

It is array inside array so you have to to do like this :

```
$.each(jsondata,function(index,item){

      $.each(item,function(index1,item1){
         if(item1.Can)
            console.log(item1.Can);
         if(item1.Bottle)
            console.log(item1.Bottle);
      });

});
```

[**FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jLSdC/)

**UPDATED:**

if you don't know what objects will be in array the you have to do recursive iteration over array:

[jQuery recursive iteration over objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203958/jquery-recursive-iteration-over-objects)

Comment: I know the values Can and Bottle exists at development time only . while dynamically reading i dont know whether this values exists .

Comment: you can check if `if(item.Can) { // then log }`

Comment: Thanks for the update i read this dynamically (JSON created from Database data) , so i really dont know if can is present or someother value is present .

Comment: do you have information how many types of objects can be returned??

Comment: No exactly , but if want i can make a database query for that .

Comment: but you have to stop somewhere you can iterate recursively all items without using object name

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203958/jquery-recursive-iteration-over-objects

Comment: Thanks Ehsan , this seems very useful utility function , but i see this doesn't fit for arrays know .

Comment: @Kiran it works, i answered someone on nested array but currentl i cannot find it in my answers

Answer (score 0):

### pure JavaScript solution

You want to use the `Object.keys()` method:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

And, you'll want to mix it with `Array.isArray()` and `Array#map()`:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

If your environment / browser doesn't have ECMAScript 5 support, then you can find a poly-fill here: https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim

My approach also uses the following from older JavaScript:

- `Array#concat()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat
- `Function#apply()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Here's how you might use it:

```
var result = [];
if (Array.isArray(jsondata.T3)) {
    result = result.concat.apply(result, jsondata.T3.map(function (obj) {
        return Object.keys(obj); // Array of Array of Strings
    }));
    /* Array#concat() used with Function#apply() to reduce
    an Array of Array of Strings down to an Array of Strings */
}
// now, result is Array ['Can', 'Bottle']
```