# HTML5 JSON MultiDimensional Arrays Keys with javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I read lots of information on the net and forums but cannot get a solution to my problem.
I have the following JSON file:

```
var data = 
{ "AA" :[{"a1":[{"ab1": [
                     {"ab1a": 10 },
                     {"ab1b": 20 },
                     {"ab1c": 30 },
                     {"ab1d": 40 }
                     ]
            },
            {"ab2":[
                     {"ab1a": 10 },
                     {"ab1b": 20 },
                     {"ab1c": 30 },
                     {"ab1d": 40 }
                    ]
            }
            ]
     }
     ,{"a2":[{"ab3": [
                     {"ab3a": 10 },
                     {"ab3b": 20 },
                     {"ab3c": 30 },
                     {"ab3d": 40 }
                     ]
             },
            {"ab4":[
                     {"ab4a": 10 },
                     {"ab4b": 20 },
                     {"ab4c": 30 },
                     {"ab4d": 40 }
                    ]
            } 
            ]
     }    
    ]
}
```

I have validated the JSON file. I want to get the keys first for `"AA"` then `"a1"` and `"a2"` and then for `"ab1"`, `"ab2"` and etc. There are questions and information about values but not the keys. Most probably jQuery might help but I am confused about how to get all the keys.

Any ideas? any hope...!

Comment: Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: you probably want to use some kind of recursive function http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203958/jquery-recursive-iteration-over-objects, optionally for loops will do fine if you know how many levels of objects you have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to getting all the keys from an object of unknown size is **recursion**. Here I have  2 solutions; one Functional and one Object Oriented. Also I created some other data to test with in addition to yours.

Here is the repo with the complete code: https://github.com/vasilionjea/json-keys

### The Data:

```
var data = {
  continents: {
    europe: {
      countries: [
        {
          'country-name': 'italy',
          cities: [
            { 'city-name': 'Rome', title: 'Roma Dolor', population:873, gdb: 301 },
            { 'city-name': 'Venice', title: 'Venice Veggies.', population:456, gdb: 244 }
          ]
        },

        {
          'country-name': 'france',
          cities: [
            { 'city-name': 'Paris', title: 'De Ipsum', population:7123, gdb: 77 },
            { 'city-name': 'Marseille', title: 'La Mipsum', population:73, gdb: 7 }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },

    'north-america': {
      countries: [
        {
          'country-name': 'canada',
          cities: [
            { 'city-name': 'Montreal', title: 'The city of lorem ipsum!', population:99, gdb: 011 },
            { 'city-name': 'Quebec', title: 'Veggie Ipsum.', population:123, gdb: 101 }
          ]
        },
        {
          'country-name': 'usa',
          cities: [
            { 'city-name': 'New York', title: 'Empire State', population:1001001, gdb: 1010 },
            { 'city-name': 'San Francisco', title: 'SF Bridge', population:20123, gdb: 202 }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

### The functional way:

```
/*
 * Functional example.
 * Retrieves all keys from an object of unknown size using recursion.
 */
function _isObject(obj) {
  return Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === "[object Object]";
}

function _eachKey(obj, callback) {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(callback);
}

var _container = [];

function collectKeys(data) {
  _eachKey(data, function(key) {
    _container.push(key);

    if (_isObject(data[key])) {
      collectKeys(data[key]);
    }

    if (Array.isArray(data[key])) {
      // Because we're looping through an array and each array's item is an object, 
      // the `collectKeys` function is receiving each object of the array as an argument.
      data[key].forEach(collectKeys);
    }
  });

  return _container;
}

// Execute the function
var myKeys = collectKeys(data);
```

### The Object Oriented way:

```
/*
 * Object Oriented example.
 * Retrieves all keys from an object of unknown size using recursion.
 */
function JSONKeys(obj) {
  this._container = [];

  if (this._isObject(obj)) {
    // Just a normal object literal.
    this._data = obj;
  } else if (typeof obj === 'string') {
    // Just in case the data was passed in as a valid JSON string.
    this._data = JSON.parse(obj);
  } else {
    throw new Error('The provided argument must be an object literal or a JSON string.');
  }
}

JSONKeys.prototype = {
  constructor: JSONKeys,

  _isObject: function(obj) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === "[object Object]";
  },

  _eachKey: function(obj, callback) {
   // Using `bind(this)` makes sure that the `this` value in the `_collect` method 
   // isn't set to the global object (window).
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(callback.bind(this));
  },

  _recur: function(key, data) {
      // If this key's value is also an object go deeper.
      if (this._isObject(data[key])) {
        this._collect(data[key]);
      }

      if (Array.isArray(data[key])) {
        // * Because we're looping through an array and each array's item is an object, 
        //   the `_collect` method is receiving each object of the array as an argument.
        // * Using `bind(this)` makes sure that the `this` value in the `_collect` method 
        //   isn't set to the global object (window).
        data[key].forEach(this._collect.bind(this));
      }
  },

  _collect: function(data) {
    this._eachKey(data, function(key) {
      this._container.push(key);

      // Continue collecting
      this._recur(key, data);
    });
  },

  getAll: function() {
    this._collect(this._data);
    return this._container;
  }
};

// Create a new instance passing the data.
var keysObject = new JSONKeys(data);
allKeys = keysObject.getAll();
```

Comment: var keys = $AA[a2][ab3].keys .Is it possible to get onliner with javascript to obtain keys out of ab3.

Comment: Yes there is. For example if I have the following data: 
`var person = {
  addresses: [
    {street: '123 main st.', number: 7, city: 'New York'},
    {street: '123 first st.', number: 99, city: 'San Francisco', state: 'CA'}
  ]
}`, and want to get the keys of the second address in the array, then I can do this: `Object.keys(person['addresses'][1]);`

Comment: I am getting somewhere..! I need to study more about Accessing Object in the Objects. when i tried "Object.keys(data['AA']['a2'][0]);" i get error data['AA']['a2'] is undefined.

Comment: That's because `data['AA']` is an array and array items can be queried by an integer (this index): `data['AA'][0]` gives you the first object in the array. So to get **a2** you would do `data['AA'][0]['a2']`. But **a2** is also an array, so getting an object in that array you would follow the same pattern. I'm confident you can figure out the rest. :)